# Evaluate complex integral using deformation theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

It's given that,
$\gamma$ is a circle of radius $r$ and centre $z=a$ inside $\Gamma$. 
I need to use the deformation theorem to evaluate this:
$$\oint_\Gamma \ (z-a)^ndz ,   n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Surely at different $n$ the answer will be different? I think the integral about $\gamma$ is: $$\oint_{0}^{2\pi} \ (z-a)^n dz$$
but the answer will be different for each integer n? I think that when n is negative the function is not analytic in the countour hence I don't think I can use Cauchy's integral formula or Cauchy's theorem. Also when n is 0 or positive i think the integral is 0 because of its analyticity on the contour

Sorry if my assumptions don't make sense, i only started the course, Thanks for any help

Comment: Hint: You can evaluate the circle integral (integral about $\gamma$) directly by parametrizing the circle.

Comment: $z\in \mathbb{Z}$? not in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I meant n, well spotted and Christopher, would parametric equation be $z=a+e^{i\theta}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $z=a+r e^{i \theta}$. Then $dz=i r e^{i \theta}$ and the contour integral becomes

$$i r^{n+1} \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i (n+1) \theta}$$

So long as $n$ is an integer, the above integral vanishes...except when $n=-1$, when it is equal to $i 2 \pi$.  Yes, even when $n$ is less than $-1$, the integral vanishes.

This is why the residue of a function is defined as the coefficient of the $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ term in the Laurent expansion about a pole $z=z_0$.  All other terms in the series vanish upon integration about a closed loop around the pole.

Comment: Lovely stuff! +1

Comment: I know now, the real part of integral becomes a cosine of even integer -1 which is always 0 and imaginary part becomes a sine of even integer which is 0. The only problem I have is where do you have $r^{n+1}$ from in front of the integral.

Comment: @KuderaSebastian: "circle of radius $r$"...look at the substitution I made.  There are $n$ $r$'s from the $(z-a)^n$ terms, and an extra $r$ from the $dz$ term.

Comment: I only had $r^2$ because I didnt raise $r$ in the bracket to the $nth$ power. Thanks for the help. Just one last thing, essentialy we have to answers yeah? 0 everywhere but $n=-1$ and i2pi when n=-1

Comment: @KuderaSebastian: "we have to have answers"...I do not know what you mean.  Is this homework?  I know nothing of your homework.  Read the problem that your teacher gave you and figure out how to answer it.  Hopefully my answer to your question at least provides a clear guide.